# Nested loops bounds

Tags: c++, loops

I have a 2D_array with size `[4344][20]`, for some reasons I want to transfer between the first 20 rows, then move to the next 20 rows, and then to next next 20 rows... etc. until reach to the last row which is row 4343.

Do I do that correct?

my code:

```
int main()
{
    int tindex = 0;
    for (int l = tindex; l + 20 < 4344; l + 20) {
        for (int u = tindex; u < tindex + 20; ++u) {
          
            ............
        }
        tindex = tindex + 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: why you do not use `l` diretly?

Comment: I'd suggest do not use `20` for both column and row-batch in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: and ofcourse `4344` would not divide by `20` so `u` would out-of bound (oh you limit by `l+20` so it'd not, instead you'd not process the last 4 rows)

Comment: @appleapple so what you recommend to use something divided by 4344 ?

Comment: @ JOJO, it's you to decide what to do for the last 4 rows.

Comment: but I definitely recommend replace the `[4344][20]` by `[4344][30]` in question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Your `l` variable never gets incremented.  There is an add expression, but the value is never assigned to `l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
/// Your code ///
int tindex = 0;
for (int l = tindex; l + 20 < 4344; l + 20) {
   for (int u = tindex; u < tindex + 20; ++u) {
       // do something
   }        
   tindex = tindex + 20;
}
```

- `tindex` is not necessary, you can use `l` directly
- `l + 20` should be `l+=20`

---

so it becomes something like

```cpp
for (int batch_begin = 0; batch_begin + 20 < 4344; batch_begin += 20) {
   for (int row = batch_begin; row < batch_begin + 20; ++row) {
   }
}
```

---

---

---

you can also use a variable to hold batch size and reuse it in both loop

```cpp
const int row_count = 4344;
const int batch_size = 20;
for (int batch_begin = 0; batch_begin + batch_size < row_count; batch_begin += batch_size) {
   for (int row = batch_begin; row < batch_begin + batch_size; ++row) {
      //do something 
   }
}
```

---

If you want to include the remained rows (the above ignore them), a simple way is use `std::min` on second loop.

```cpp
const int row_count = 4344;
const int batch_size = 20;
for (int batch_begin = 0; batch_begin + batch_size < row_count; batch_begin += batch_size) {
   for (int row = batch_begin; row < std::min(batch_begin + batch_size, row_count); ++row) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: what about  4344 would not divide by 20 ?? Do I need to use number other than 20 ??

Comment: @JOJO as I said in comment in question. **you** should decide **what you want** to do with remained 4 rows (as the code currently stand it ignore them)

Comment: I need the last 4 rows to be included. So what do you suggest ?

Comment: @JOJO you can simply change end condition of second for-loop, I've add an example to the answer .

Comment: not alloweded to use std

Comment: what about replace `20` by `8` since `4344` is divided by '8' ??

Comment: @JOJO `std::min` is trivil (well at least min of two `int` is trivial), you can implement it yourself, and **do not ask me about your requirement** you say you need 20 so the answer is based on 20, I even provide parameterized code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with C++ (from C++11 onward).
Though I probably wouldn't even use the array directly but wrap it in a class and pass the class around. (And I would name the class after WHAT it is representing, the array is just the HOW). I would also make any operations on the array member functions of the class.

So my question is what does the array represent?

```
#include <utility>

// only use "magic" numbers once in your code
constexpr std::size_t rows_v = 4344;
constexpr std::size_t cols_v = 20;

// this is the syntax for passing your array to a function
void loop_over_array(const int(&arr)[rows_v][cols_v])
{
    // this example uses range based for loops
    // which cannot go out of bound of the array
    // loop over all the rows in your array
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

    for (auto& row : arr)
    {
        // loop over all the values in your row
        for (auto& value : row)
        {
            // do something with value;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int my_array[rows_v][cols_v]{}; // initialize array to all 0
    loop_over_array(my_array);
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use classes. my code is long and I need this specific part. I can't add classes in this part

Comment: Oh ok, that's too bad. Oh well at least I hope you learned something from this example. 
At least remember this passing arrays as int** looses a lot of information and should in my opinion not be used. And in modern C++ std::array, std::vector are much better to use (and you can tell your teacher that)